# Using Handlebars to color dynamically

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm looping through an object and displaying a resulting table using handlebars.

If a certain number is greater than 50, I want to style the number one color, and if it's less than 50, I want to style it with another color.

I'm pretty new to handlebars, so I'm having trouble figuring out how I'd do the logic. I looked into custom helpers, but I'm not sure how I'd write out the custom HTML/CSS needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the desired color as an input object. Prior to defining your template, set the color dynamically based on your number.

Extending the official handlebars sample (https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#installation):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
<!-- Include Handlebars from a CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
<script>
  // compile the template
  var template = Handlebars.compile("<div style='color: {{textColor}}''>Handlebars <b>{{doesWhat}}</b>");

  var amount = 55;
  var color = amount > 50 ? "red" : "green"

  document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = template({ doesWhat: "rocks!", textColor: color });
</script>
</html>
```